# React Navigation onPress function in own tabBarButton?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am kind of begginer, I need to make component for tabBarButton and i made it.

Problem is that navigation doesnt work now, because I have no idea how to write onPress function to make it work!

Anyone can help me with thsi one please?

This is my component, that I use in my `Tab.Navigator` :

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Text from '../Text/Text';

interface Props {}

const NavBottomButton: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const {children} = props;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style={styles.navButton}>
      <View>
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navButton: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default NavBottomButton;
```

And here is how i use my Component :

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={someStyles}>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Matches"
    component={Matches}
    options={{
      tabBarButton: (props) => (
        <NavBottomButton onPress={Matches} {...props}>
          {i18n.t('matchesPage.tabTitle')}
        </NavBottomButton>
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Groups"
    component={Groups}
    options={{
      tabBarButton: (props) => (
        <NavBottomButton onPress={Groups} {...props}>
          {i18n.t('groupsPage.tabTitle')}
        </NavBottomButton>
      ),
    }}
  />     
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Right now i dont know how to create `onPress` function, for `TouchableOpacity`, please help me.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I want to navigate to screens, which are used as components in <Tab.Screen component={} />

But i cant untill i write right onPress function. And I have no idea how to write onPress function

Comment: ok so you want to access navigation from here ? then you can use navigation.navigate

Comment: Can you show me an example? because i was trying to use it. I just make mistake somewhere and it doesnt work. Maybe i dont import something, or i just do mistake somewhere else. 

I tryed  onPress={() => navigation.navigate(Matches)}, and code shows me that i cant put element in there.

Comment: Please check the answer and see if that sorts your issue :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working sample for you which gets access to navigation via the options and call navigation.navigate.

You can pass the same onPress to your custom component as a prop and use it there

```
 <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarButton: (props) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
              <Text>Settings</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Works like a charm bro... 

Comment: Just wrap the "Settings" in a Text component `<View>settings</View>`

Comment: You cannot render text inside TouchableOpacity unless you wrap it in Text component

Comment: @dontdownvoteme this is just a sample code thanks for pointing it out I fixed it

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan its has been suggested a long time ago

Comment: @dontdownvoteme its updated now :)